# pageContainer loading external page is not working in jquery mobile 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

My question is simple I didn't get right answer.Using jquery mobile v1.4.2

**Working**
Calling second page within same file

```
 $(document).bind('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
      $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#indexx", { role: "page" , transition:"flip"} );
  });
```

**Not Working**:
Likewise I tried to load external page

```
 $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){
                $("a").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", "secondpage.html", { role: "page" , transition:"flip"} );
         });
  });
```

Thanks is advance

Comment: Before I give you my answer tell me what do you expect from not working code snippet?

Comment: I tried many times it is not loading the external page.. I am totally confused

Comment: What do you expect when page is loaded, do you think it should open at that point?

Comment: No no for example I gave like that .... problem is that pagecontainer code is not working if i use load

Comment: Are you receiving an error or nothing happens?

Comment: Also copy this code snippet: $(document).on('pageload', function(){   alert('test'); }); and test it in your code, alert should trigger if page was successfully loaded with pagecontainer load.

Comment: freshly pressed: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/